# Is it possible to create an extension method both for Int32 and Int64?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Let's say I've an extension method like this one

```
public static IEnumerable<int> DoThings(this int n)
{
    var mList = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var result = new List<int>();
    foreach(var m in mList)
        result.Add(n * m);

    return result;
}
```

Is there a way to "genericize" so i can use it also on `long` and get a `IEnumerable<long>` as a result?

if I go simply with `public static IEnumerable<T> DoThings<T>(this T n)` its hard to do the math without ending in Cast<> and Convert vortex

Comment: Unfortunutely not possible with generics as there is no generic constraint for "numeric" types.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to multiply every item by a fixed value, `items.Select(m=>m*n)`. If you want to calculate the product of a list, you could use `Enumerable.Aggregate()`, eg `items.Aggregate(
    (runningProduct, nextFactor) => runningProduct * nextFactor);`.

Comment: no, the code is just an example... I'm factoring numbers

Comment: Why not just use long? That type will cope with the biggest range of values.

Comment: Unlike some languages, C# does not have something like `T where T implements operator*(T, T)`, so you can't write genericized numerics. You're basically stuck with implementing it once either for the biggest type you want to support (and letting the caller handle conversions back to a smaller domain), or implementing it once for every type, so you can handle any range issues yourself. Also consider something like `BigInteger` for arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: You can see how .NET solves this problem [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535184(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You can do something similar with `dynamic`, but you lose compile type checking.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucabol/2009/02/05/simulating-inumeric-with-dynamic-in-c-4-0/

Answer (score -3):

There´s no generic constraint that would fit for only `Int32` (which is `int`) and `Int64` (which is `long`), while *not* fitting for any other numeric type.

However you can just create **two** extension-methods where one references the other:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> DoThings(this int n)
{
    return DoThings((long) n).Cast<int>();
}
public static IEnumerable<long> DoThings(this long n)
{
    var mList = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var result = new List<long>();
    foreach(var m in mList)
        result.Add(n * m);

    return result;
}
```

Be aware that the result may also exceed the max-number for `Int32`, in which case you´d get an `InvalidCastException` when calling the `int`-version.

However as an `int` can implicitely be cast to `long` anyway, I can't see why you even *want* two methods. Stay with that for `long` and forget about the `int`-version altogether.

Comment: Shouldn't `DoThings(this Int16 n)` return `IEnumerable<int16>`?

Comment: @Backs Multiplying two 16-bit numbers can return up to 32 bits. Something the OP should take into consideration

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Depends on whether the project is set to checked or unchecked arithmetic.  The default is unchecked, so it'd just compute the wrong value, not throw.